# How do (did) you remember the meaning for 迫(廹)?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

> 迫：coerce, force, compel; urgent

What are the tricks you use to memorize its meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a mnemonic might be:

walk 辶 chuò in the moonlight 白 bái ：

you can't go home, you are forced to wander the roads alone under the moonlight

Answer (score 0):

辶 = looks like a horse.

白 = a white knight.

The white knight "force, compel" the horse to gallop "urgently"